# C++11 regex_search not working but regex_match is

Tags: regex, c++11

I'm trying to parse a string from a file using regex in C++ but when I read the string from the file, regex_search is not working:

```
  string stream;

  ifstream file("weather.txt");
  stream.assign( (istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)),
                (istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

  const string s = stream;
  regex rgx("[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}");
  smatch match;

  for(i=0; i < 12; i++){
    if (regex_search(s, match, rgx))
        cout << "match: " << match[i] << '\n';
  }
```

But if I do a regex_match(), it works:

```
  if (regex_match(s, rgx));
    cout <<" YEass";
```

I tried with a simple string and it worked, but when I read the content from the file it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

When you use regex_search and you expect to get more than 1 result
you have to use iterators (pointers) to advance to the next start position
within the string.

Example

```
std::string::const_iterator start, end;
start = s.begin();
end   = s.end();
smatch m;

while ( regex_search( start, end, m, rx ) )
{
    // do something with the results
    std::string sgrp1(m[1].first, m[1].second);
    std::string sgrp2(m[2].first, m[2].second);
    std::string sgrp3(m[3].first, m[3].second);
    // etc, ...

    // update search position: 
    start = m[0].second;
}
```

What you are actually doing is trying to re-match the entire string
12 times in order to display the individual 12 groups one at a time,
which is not the way to go.

If you indeed have 12 groups, you only need to match once then iterate
over the match results once.

```
if ( regex_search( start, end, m, rx ) )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 12; i++ )
    {
         std::string str(m[i].first, m[i].second);
         cout << "group " << i << " = " << str << "\r\n";
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I couldn't test it yet but I didn't quite understand the string groups in the first example. Each string group would be a match from the search? And what exactly are the first and second objects from m? Sorry, it's the first time I'm using this regex library and I'm not familiar with it yet.

Comment: I tried the two options but still regex_search keeps returning false :(

Comment: _`match_results`_ is an indexed collection of sub-expression matches. Objects of type _`sub_match`_ may only be obtained by subscripting an object of type match_results. I.e `m[i]`. Each sub_match represents a _group_ defined in the regex, like `(abc)(def)(ghi)(jk)` has 4 groups. But your regex `[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}` has no groups. In fact when you try to index the match object via `m[i]` in your loop, it should throw a runtime error.